How to get other prompts to stop
I want the other inputs to stop running if the user isn't Chai or 35. When I run it even if the person isn't meeting conditions it continues.
user = input("What is your name? \n")
if user == "Chai":

    age = int(input("Oh really? How old are you? \n"))
    if age <= 34:
        print("Lmao nice try kiddo")

    elif age >= 100:
        print("uh GTFO Dracula!")

    elif age == 35:
        name = input("Welcome back! Who's info do you need saved? \n")
    elif age >= 36:
        print("Bye Felcia!")

elif user == "Boots":
    print("pspspsp here kitty!")
else:
    print("Access Denied")

    # Inputs here

note = input("What note do you want here? \n")
bday = input("What is their birthday or zodiac sign? \n")

How can I stop the other inputs from appearing after the first two didn't match up to Chai and 35?

maybe you have to put inputs in some if/else like if user == "Chai" and age == 35: do_something
